# using slowly changing dimension added a slicer for date range. Need to receive the min and max of a date rage and to 'spread' it over the table

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation

Using time range in a slicer [time range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mie1N.png)
The expected result: for MIN('Time'[TIME_ID]) :[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YleBW.png)
The actual result: [Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFknG.png)
Thanks in advance

tried to use calculate(min(Time)) but it didn't work as expected.y

Answer (score 0):

**Calculate MIN measure:**

```
MIN = CALCULATE(MINX('Calendar',[Date]),ALL('Calendar'))
```

**For Actual Date, you can put [Date] column again into table:**

[image]